# Data manipulation of geodatabase in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, fiona

I have a large geodatabase (`.gdb`) file that I need to filter through using Python.  I have Python 3.4 on my work machine.

I tried using fiona to read the gdb and its layers.  I keep getting the same error:

> gdb = fiona.open('GDB Path')
>
> Error message:  embedded NUL character.

How can I best fix this?